# What is the difference between a census and a parameter in statistics?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, definition

I'm going through my class textbook and the definition for a census is

> When desired information is available for all objects in the population, we have what is called a census.

I remember from biostatistics that a parameter is essentially a characteristic of an entire population while a statistic is a characteristic about a sample. Are the terms parameter and census synonymous then? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_parameter (see the first sentence). So, for example, a population mean, population standard deviation, population 90th percentile, population regression slope, etc. A census is a complete collection of some quantity (or quantities) of interest for all of the members of the population. If you have a census you could (at least in principle) compute a population parameter.

Answer (score -1):

We generally call it as parameter when we don't have its true value and we would like to make a inference over it, we call census when we just evaluate some quantity over all population.

Comment: This is incorrect: the definition of parameter quoted in the question is the correct one and is fully general.  It does *not* depend on your state of mind or knowledge of it.  The problem with this question is that a parameter and a census are such completely different things that they cannot even be compared and contrasted.

Comment: what would be your answer

Comment: Look at any definition of these terms in an authoritative textbook.